# Python/Selenium - no such element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma automação em Python com a biblioteca selenium para acessar o site do Econet e retirar os dados de uma tabela a partir de um código de NCM. De inicio escrevi o código para abrir o navegador, acessar a parte do usuário e de pesquisa para NCM's. Porém ao clicar no campo para inserir o NCM me encontro com o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/gusta/PyCharmProjects/WebScraping/tes.py", line 32, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input').click()   #click no campo para inserir o NCM
  File "C:\Users\gusta\PyCharmProjects\WebScraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\gusta\PyCharmProjects\WebScraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\gusta\PyCharmProjects\WebScraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\gusta\PyCharmProjects\WebScraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.121)
```

Segue abaixo o código:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
# --- #

# --- # chamando o chrome --- #
chromedriver = "C:/Users/gusta/Downloads/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)

url = 'http://www.econeteditora.com.br/'

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(0)

# --- #

login = "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input"
senha = "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input[1]"

# --- # login econet
driver.find_element_by_xpath(login).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(login).send_keys("")  #usuário
driver.find_element_by_xpath(senha).click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath(senha).send_keys("")  #senha
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/img').click()
time.sleep(2)

# --- # busca ncm

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[16]/a').click()     #click na barra de opções lado esquerdo (NCM)
time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input').click()   #click no campo para inserir o NCM

time.sleep(2)

# --- #
#driver.quit()
```

Comment: Gustavo, bom dia! No seu código original com 'usuario' e 'senha' você consegue acessar a próxima pagina?

Comment: Imonferrari, bom dia! Consigo sim. Quando ele precisa fazer o click na linha 32, ele me apresenta o erro.

Answer (score 0):

Como eu não tenho acesso a página, tente dessa forma:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

# --- # chamando o chrome --- #
chromedriver = "./chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
url = 'http://www.econeteditora.com.br/'
driver.get(url)

# --- #
login = 'Log'
senha = 'Sen'
input_log = 'btn_logar'

# --- # login econet

driver.find_element_by_name(login).send_keys('teste')
driver.find_element_by_name(senha).send_keys('teste')
driver.find_element_by_id(input_log).click()

# --- # busca ncm
delay = 5
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]/div[3]/div[1]/ul/li[16]/a'))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/form/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input'))).click()
except TimeoutException:
    print('Tempo esgotado.')
# --- #
#driver.quit()
```

Foi adicionado um tempo de espera que pode ser alterado na variável delay.